# What are some of the empirical proofs of electromagnetic polarization?

Tags: visible-light, waves, maxwell-equations, polarization

I am aware of how polarization follows from Maxwell's equations, and how it is possible in transverse waves in general. I also know that Huygens, in his great *Treatise on Light*, first discovered and described polarization by looking very carefully at a piece of Iceland spar.

I am interested in more modern empirical evidence for polarization. What are some experiments that reveal EM polarization to be at work in precisely the way we would expect? How 'fine grained' can we get in our description of the field and the phenomena involved?

As an example of the sort of answer I am looking for, one might offer the example of a polaroid filter. I know how such filters are expected to behave, but I do not know *how* we know the light passing through such a filter is polarized as expected.

The more examples the better!

Comment: This seems to be extremely broad - are you actually questioning the ability to express waves as two orthogonal components, or the fact that optics calculations relying on this ability are able to exquisitely predict observations?

Comment: I am questioning neither. I am confused how you are confused. What I am asking about is in the title of the question, made more specific in the second paragraph, and quite explicit in the example I give. My question is not broad, but specific. I am not questioning Maxwell's equations, or the fact that optics calculations relying on those equations are able to exquisitely predict observations, I AM ASKING FOR SOME OF THE OBSERVATIONS they predict. I kind of went out of my way to make that clear. I really don't think the question is broad at all, much less extremely broad.

Comment: Would something to the effect of measuring the polarization *before* a polarizer and then *after* it be what you're after?

Comment: I think so. I am interested in *how* we would measure polarization in general.

Comment: Modern polarization measurements are very easy because of the availability of materials with very well defined polarization selectivity. Would you be happy with answer that start out *"order a good set of linear Polaroid sheets, and when they arrive ..."*, or are you interested in how the knowledge of these things is bootstrapped from basic principles?

Comment: I think a little of both. I wanted more examples of the first kind other than polarization sheets and other obvious things -- that's mainly what I was asking for -- but the real reason for asking the question was more of the second kind, bootstrapping from principles, explaining *why*. Sure, I can do a polaroid experiment, but *how* do I know it's confirming polarization? It's good to have a list of observations confirmed by theory, but better is to have a narrative about how the observations actually happen. This yields the kind of understanding I'm looking for.

Comment: I'll second Jon - this isn't really clear. Does the fact that polaroid filters can be quite easily shown to obey [Malus's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarizer#Malus.27_law_and_other_properties) not enough? There are plenty of simple ways to measure e.g. the [Stokes parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes_parameters) of a light beam, which are all detailed in any optics textbook. What is it about your question that isn't already in a textbook?

Comment: In what world does a derived law stated in a textbook, or a mathematical parametrization, count as an empirical proof? Is the difference between a mathematical rule and the empirical observation it predicts actually so difficult to keep in mind? As for textbooks (a completely different issue), the reason I ask questions here is that other people know more than me about most things. I thought that was the purpose of sites like this? If you made 'not already in a textbook' a requisite for asking a question here you would destroy the site (not the mention insist on an unenforceable condition).

Comment: Also, if you had said to me: the polaroid filter obeys Malus's law *and this is how we know*, that would be a perfect example of answering the question in the way  I outlined in paragraph 3 of the original post. I didn't know about Malus's law before. I like learning, that's why I ask questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Newer 3D movies use two images projected with different and orthogonal polarizations. The viewer 3D glasses have two orthogonal polarizers. This would not have worked if polarization can't be separated.
2. Polarized sunglasses work better than normal sunglasses by taking advantage of light becoming polarized after reflection. The sunglasses filter out the reflected light and let directly transmitted light pass. Again, this would have not worked without separable and orthogonal two-components polarization.
3. The twisted nematic effect which makes modern LCD technology possible relies entirely on polarization. ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twisted_nematic_field_effect))
4. In fact, upon quick Googling, there are many more examples on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_(waves)#Measurement_techniques_involving_polarization).

Comment: This is great, thanks, especially #3. I should have stated explicitly in the question that I was looking for things that weren't in Wikipedia, but since I failed to do that you answered the question quite nicely. I'll leave it open a bit longer to see what others might come up with and if nobody improves on your quite extensive list I'll accept. Cheers.

Comment: In addition, light can be shown to carry angular momentum, with left- and right-handed circularly polarized light having opposite angular momenta. Spectroscopic experiments support this.

Comment: Note that modern 3D movies do *not* use linear polarization states. If they did you would get confused and dizzy anytime you tilted your head. instead they use the two different circular polarization states.

Comment: @dmckee, well I didn't know about the linear vs circular polarization in movie. But, trying to get myself out of it in anyway I can, orthogonal doesn't connote linear polarization. Two circular polarizations can be orthogonal too. :P Thank you for adding to my answer.